# Why DeviceIoControl sometimes not working (error=2)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

```
DISK_PERFORMANCE DiskPerformance = {0};

DWORD dwDiskInfoSize = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

    std::printf("Try %d th Open \\\\.\\c:\n", i);

    HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\c:",
                                0,
                                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                //SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES,
                                NULL,
                                OPEN_EXISTING,
                                0,
                                NULL);
    std::printf("hDevice = %p\n", hDevice);

    if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::printf("CreateFile failed  = %d \n", GetLastError());

        continue;
    }

    if (!DeviceIoControl(hDevice,
                         IOCTL_DISK_PERFORMANCE,
                         NULL,
                         0,
                         &DiskPerformance,
                         sizeof(DiskPerformance),
                         &dwDiskInfoSize,
                         NULL))
    {

        CloseHandle(hDevice);

        std::printf("DeviceIoControl failed  = %d \n", GetLastError());

        continue;
    }

    std::printf("QuDeviceIoControlery Success\n");

    CloseHandle(hDevice);

    Sleep(1000);

    std::printf("\n\n");
}
```

I restart the program and about 95% DeviceIoControl will get the `error 2` and 5% get the correct result....

I can not reproduce the error for another machine because this code is 100% working on my laptop (win10).

My target OS is Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Unless `log_sys()` throws an exception or terminates the process, you are calling `DeviceIoControl()` with an invalid handle if `CreateFile()` fails.

Comment: But CreateFile successfully

Comment: even so, it is still a bug in your code that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I add "return" when if CreateFile() fails, but my problem is not solved.

Comment: I wasn’t suggesting that was THE cause of your problem, only that it was A problem.

Comment: How is `DiskPerformance` defined?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT    DISK_PERFORMANCE DiskPerformance = {0};

Comment: It's not necessary to share `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE` access when requesting 0 access (in practice: `SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES`). If the access is a subset of `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY | SYNCHRONIZE | WRITE_OWNER | WRITE_DAC | READ_CONTROL | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES`, the volume device is opened directly instead of the mounted filesystem device, so share access is irrelevant. It's relevant if volume data access is required because I/O requests route through the filesystem, which may have the volume locked or need to implicitly lock the volume.

Comment: I add `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE`, and it is not working `error = 87`

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce your problem. I will discuss with relevant engineers and update the result  here.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT Is this a bug in win2016 server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The disk performance counters in Windows Server 2016 are turned off by default.

You can run CMD as admin and enter `diskperf -Y` to enable the disk counter of the task manager.

[image]